# Usage of this and that almost interchangeably

Tags: that, this-that

Here and there the usage of the words *this* and *that* look artbitrary and often completely interchangeably.

Example

> Today the politician Pete Brown stated that the CIA bribed the
>   president's advisors. This is of course not true.

The word *this* in the above sentence should refer to the sentence itself shouldn't it? And the sentence should be more correct if it was "That is of course not true."

Is my observation true? If yes, why is that ("this(?)") often done?

Isn't the word *this* a self-referential word so that logically, saying *This is not true* is a contradiction in terms?

Comment: No, that is not true.

Comment: *This* in the sentence is a pronoun,so it has an antecedent, i.e., something to which it refers (not itself). In this case, a charge of bribery. **This** reference to bribery (my reference) is nearer, and **that** reference to bribery (yours) is farther away, syntactically speaking. Sometimes either pronoun will do.

Comment: *This* is here and *that* is over there.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, it depends on the point of view. 'This' refers to 'this one over here' while 'that' refers to 'that one over there'.

In practice then, 'this one is red' and 'that one is red' might be interchangeable on the level of colour but that's only one kettle of herring and from other perspectives, the similarity is less important than the difference.

Although it's fairly loose, 'Today… Pete Brown stated…' is 'over there' because it has nothing to do with the speaker.

In this case '*This* is of course not true' is 'over here' largely because although stated as a fact, it is clearly the view of the speaker.

'*That* is of course not true' would be somehow intermediate; still stated as a fact but perhaps not so clearly the view of the speaker.

Comment: Uh… thanks Bladorthin and if there's a rule that seasonal greetings aren't encouraged then for politeness, courtesy and general good feeling, that rule should be changed yesterday.

While I can imagine that the powers that be won't agree, that's not a reason for anyone to voluntarily uphold such an antisocial rule.

Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year

Comment: There's also the fact that “Happy New Year” will read as a bit of a non-sequitur to someone reading this in September.

Comment: Uh… if he can't read the date:time stamp, it might.

Happy New Year